# Testing of a Reporting Tool

Tags: automated-testing, performance-testing

I want to test a reporting tool for Call Center Performance.  There are too many exceptions and I want to test every possible case. How can I ensure that numbers in these reports are correct, do you know any tool will help me?

Comment: The question is too broad, can you elaborate more ? You will probably need to think about test oracles and test data but which environment ? what data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific tool to ensure the numbers in your report are correct. Because the numbers are the product of business logic application that is always different.

**One of the ways to test report numbers would be the following:**

You develop automated script using programming language you know best of all. That script downloads the report from your app (as CSV file for example), your script pics particular value, your script runs the query against the database and applies the logic that reproduces the logic executed by your application under test. Then your script compares two numbers.

**Another way might be the following:**

You have a report golden source. That could be some pre-generated report for some specific time period in the past and you are sure that report is correct. Then when you run regression against your app, you download the report for the same period and compare it value by value.